# Convert results into a dataframe from function

Tags: r

From this results:

```
library(stm)
labelTopics(gadarianFit, n = 15)

Topic 1 Top Words:
     Highest Prob: immigr, illeg, legal, border, will, need, worri, work, countri, mexico, life, better, nation, make, worker 
     FREX: border, mexico, mexican, need, concern, fine, make, better, worri, nation, deport, worker, will, econom, poor 
     Lift: cross, racism, happen, other, continu, concern, deport, mexican, build, fine, econom, border, often, societi, amount 
     Score: immigr, border, need, will, mexico, illeg, mexican, worri, concern, legal, nation, fine, worker, better, also 
Topic 2 Top Words:
     Highest Prob: job, illeg, tax, pay, american, take, care, welfar, crime, system, secur, social, health, cost, servic 
     FREX: cost, health, servic, welfar, increas, loss, school, healthcar, job, care, medic, crime, social, violenc, educ 
     Lift: violenc, expens, opportun, cost, healthcar, loss, increas, gang, servic, medic, health, diseas, terror, school, lose 
     Score: job, welfar, crime, cost, tax, care, servic, increas, health, pay, school, loss, medic, healthcar, social 
Topic 3 Top Words:
     Highest Prob: peopl, come, countri, think, get, english, mani, live, citizen, learn, way, becom, speak, work, money 
     FREX: english, get, come, mani, back, becom, like, think, new, send, right, way, just, live, peopl 
     Lift: anyth, send, still, just, receiv, deserv, back, new, english, mani, get, busi, year, equal, come 
     Score: think, peopl, come, get, english, countri, mani, speak, way, send, back, money, becom, learn, live
```

How is it possible to keep the results from highest propability into a dataframe with number of columns equal to the number of topic and rows equal to the number of words per topic (n = 15)

Example of expected output:

```
topic1 topic2 topic3
immigr job peopl
illeg illeg come
```

Comment: Please make this a reproducible question, including sample data (perhaps a dataset existing in base R) and the expected output given that sample data.

Comment: @r2evans it is a reproducible example. I update only with the output it gives

Comment: I'm glad you got an answer, but for somebody like me not already fluent in `stm`, it is not. (What R objects are used? What is returned? What is the structure of the return value?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `labelTopics` object, words are stored under `prob`. So you could try something like this:

```r
library(stm)
topics <- labelTopics(gadarianFit, n=15)

topics <- data.frame(t(topics$prob))
colnames(topics) <- paste0("topic", 1:ncol(topics))
topics
#>     topic1   topic2  topic3
#> 1   immigr      job   peopl
#> 2    illeg    illeg    come
#> 3    legal      tax countri
#> 4   border      pay   think
#> 5     will american     get
#> 6     need     take english
#> 7    worri     care    mani
#> 8     work   welfar    live
#> 9  countri    crime citizen
#> 10  mexico   system   learn
#> 11    life    secur     way
#> 12  better   social   becom
#> 13  nation   health   speak
#> 14    make     cost    work
#> 15  worker   servic   money
```

Note that `stm` offers several ways of selecting the most important words per topic, including "Frex", "Lift". You would simply have to change the `prob` in my code to use those.

Type this to see them:

```r
topics <- labelTopics(gadarianFit, n=15)
str(topics)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. But why it has highest score, frex and lift options?

Comment: The different measures are described in the documentation. Type: `?labelTopics`. I'm sure you can find academic articles on the subject, probably linked from the `stm` website.

Comment: Thank you very much. Have you every used before stm()? Because I try to find if there is a specific coherence measure